# Webpack - Serve external static resources in development

Tags: spring, webpack, jhipster

I have a Jhipster (4.14.3) application where images are downloaded from 3rd party sources on a `@Scheduled` cron, and are served as static resources. When running the project for development purposes with `mvnw -Pdev,webpack` & `yarn start`, the images are inaccessible. When packaging and executing the war, the resources are available as expected. 
`mvnw package -Pdev -DskipTests && java -jar target\foo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

`localhost:8080/images/FOO/someimage-0.png`: Works
`localhost:9000/images/FOO/someimage-0.png`: Cannot GET /images/FOO/someimage-0.png

I've set up the resource handler below for the external resources. All remote images are downloaded to this directory.

```
    @Configuration
    public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        String s = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "images").toString() + File.separator;
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:///" + s);
        }
    }
```

The image location is pulled from the database, and displayed:
`<img [src]="entry.photo.location">` => '/images/FOO/someimage-0.png'

Is there a way to configure the Spring or Webpack that I can view the resources while developing?

Comment: I can do that for testing purposes I suppose. New images are continuously downloaded so, any new images downloaded after placing them in `/resources/static` would be broken. I'd like to keep the images out of the project itself.

Comment: Try adding a proxy path in `webpack/webpack.dev.js` (around line 20), that may explain why port 8080 works but port 9000 (the webpack proxy) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact it works with port 8080 but not port 9000, the issue is with the Webpack proxy.  In the file `webpack/webpack.dev.js`, add `/images` to the proxy configuration.  This will proxy `localhost:9000/images` to `localhost:8080/images`

The final configuration should look like below:

```
    proxy: [{
        context: [
            '/images', // **Add this line**
            /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
            '/api',
            '/management',
            '/swagger-resources',
            '/v2/api-docs',
            '/h2-console',
            '/auth'
        ],
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        secure: false
    }],
```